# What do I need to do to use linkedin as a sign up method to a newly created app?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am the creator of an app, (not the developer of it) and I want to allow users to sign in with their Linkedin account. What do I need to do in order to do that?
Example: I want users to be able to sign up to my app, the same way many apps use facebook to sign up. Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement OAuth authentication in your application to use LinkedIn or Gmail as your sign-up method.

[Authenticating with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication)